# "Empty database file" exception when trying to open an Access database file with Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

It seems the Jackcess encrypt is not able to open the file supplied.

**Here is the code.**
What I am trying to do is open the database which is password protected and export the specified table as a .csv file.

```
    public class DBTool {
    private final String source = "/Users/myMac/Desktop/database.mdb";
    private final String destination = "/Users/myMac/Desktop/table.csv";
    private File sourceF;
    private File destinationF;
    private Database db;

    public DBTool() {

    }

    public void openEDB(){
        sourceF = new File(source);
        try {
            db = new DatabaseBuilder(sourceF)
                    .setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider("password"))
                    .open();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void exportDB(){
        sourceF = new File(destination);
        try {
            ExportUtil.exportFile(db, "TableName", destinationF);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here are the errors**
I can't seem to figure out how to simply open the file to be exported.

```
java.io.IOException: Empty database file
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.JetFormat.getFormat(JetFormat.java:276)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:378)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:248)
    at accesstoolssim.DBTool.openEDB(DBTool.java:30)
    at accesstoolssim.AccessToolsSim.main(AccessToolsSim.java:9)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportUtil.exportFile(ExportUtil.java:204)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportUtil.exportFile(ExportUtil.java:172)
    at accesstoolssim.DBTool.exportDB(DBTool.java:39)
    at accesstoolssim.AccessToolsSim.main(AccessToolsSim.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the database the "normal" way, i.e. `db = DatabaseBuilder.open(sourceF);` to see what that does?

Comment: Same output because the file is empty so it hits the .open and spits out Empty database file. I don't think it could be a problem with the source itself either I use the DB and it works great in Access.

Comment: In `openEDB()` try checking `sourceF.length()` to make sure it is non-zero. Also, I think you want `destinationF = new File(destination);` in `ExportDB`.

Comment: SourceF.length(); returned 0. and I definitely wanted destinationF not source. So if the length of the file is zero using the variable as well as the full path could it be a path issue? Or deeper issues with the method I am using to open the file? Opening the file is what stumped me everything else seems pretty strait forward after that. Thanks for the tips so far.

Comment: Yes, it is almost certainly a case of the `source` string not actually pointing to the input .mdb file. Double-check, and if you happen to be working on a non-Windows machine remember that *nix paths and filenames are case-sensitive (I don't remember if Macs are too).

Comment: You can also test whether the source file you are trying to use actually exists by checking the value of `sourceF.exists()`.

Comment: Thank you, after switching to my VM I was able to get the program working in windows (all I need it to work with is windows)

Comment: The problem was the file path. Everything else is great except that the first row which is normally sorted by the first column (key) has jumped down to 10

Comment: Sorry for the multiple messages apparently the return key on iOS is send. But anyways the keys are ordered 0 - 5000 and 0 isn't the first when I export its the 10th ... Weird

Comment: `ExportUtil.exportWriter` can work from a Cursor (details [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ExportUtil.html#exportWriter(com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Cursor,%20java.io.BufferedWriter,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20char,%20com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportFilter))) so you might be able to use that option to control the order of the export. Give it a try and [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.io.IOException: Empty database file
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.JetFormat.getFormat(JetFormat.java:276)
```

is telling you that Jackcess thinks the file you are trying to open contains no bytes. Even an Access database with no (user) tables, queries, etc., will still have a non-zero file size because of the system objects that must be present in order for it to be a valid database file.

So, either the file you are trying to open actually exists but is zero-length, or the path you have supplied is not valid.